# Regex having optional groups with non-capturing groups

Tags: python, regex

I have an Regex with multiple optional and Non-Capturing Groups. All of these groups can occur, but don't have to. The Regex should use Non-Capturing Groups to [return the whole string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

When I set the last group also as optional, the Regex will have several grouped results. When I set the first group as not-optional, the Regex matches. Why is that?

The input will be something like `input_text = "xyz T1 VX N1 "`, expected output `T1 VX N1`.

```
regexs = {
    "allOptional": 'p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\\s?(?:N[X0-3])?',
    "lastNotOptional": 'p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\\s?(?:N[X0-3])',
    "firstNotOptional": 'p?(?:T[X0-4]?)\\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\\s?(?:N[X0-3])?',
}

for key, regex in regexs.items():
    matches = re.findall(regex, input_text)

    # Results
    allOptional = ['', '', '', ' ', 'T1 VX N1', '']
    lastNotOptional = ['T1 VX N1']
    firstNotOptional = ['T1 VX N1']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Non-capture groups don't return anything.

Comment: `p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\s?(?:N[X0-3])?` the all optional will match at every character position. This should be avoided as it includes the trivial solutions as well.

Comment: You can avoid the trivia by requiring something `^(?![\s]*$)p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\s?(?:N[X0-3])?$` This forces it to match something non-whitespace, while allowing all segments to be optional.

Comment: This will not match anything, the returned value is just ''. Maybe then I'll just use the first Item as non optional..

Comment: Can you provide input_text? It seems regex matches because you have this group in your input_text.

Comment: Without input-expected output it is not possible to help.

Comment: It's going to match all optional left to right, just no white space or empty strings only. https://regex101.com/r/TrqGf1/1

Comment: If you have a situation where any part can be in any order that's more complex but doable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and your regex101. It's totally possible that there're more Strings at the end. There can be String before, but this is unlikely. E.g. there can be a occurance of G1 at the end: https://regex101.com/r/1cZ6iJ/1

Comment: Before after, in the middle, really doesn't matter as long as one of those optional things are on the line. Can even just do away with matching anything else [(?=(?:p|T\[X0-4\]?|V\[X0-2\]|N\[X0-3\]))p?(?:T\[X0-4\]?)?\[ \t\]?(?:V\[X0-2\])?\[ \t\]?(?:N\[X0-3\])?](https://regex101.com/r/J5Z1z4/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```py
\b(?=\w)p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\s?(?:N[X0-3])?\b(?<=\w)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gqRbG/1).

Alternative for this is a combination of lookarounds that make sure the match is immediately preceded with a whitespace char or start of string, and the first char of a match is a whitespace char, and another lookaround combination (at the end of the pattern) to make sure the match end char is a non-whitespace and then a whitespace or end of string follows:

```py
(?<!\S)(?=\S)p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\s?(?:N[X0-3])?(?!\S)(?<=\S)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gqRbG/2).

The main point here are two specific word/whitespace boundaries:

- `\b(?=\w)`  at the start makes sure the word boundary position is matched, that is immediately followed with a word char
- `\b(?<=\w)` at the end asserts the position at the word boundary, with a word char immediately on the left
- `(?<!\S)(?=\S)` - a position that is at the start of string, or immediately after a whitespace and that is immediately followed with a non-whitespace char
- `(?!\S)(?<=\S)` - a position that is at the end of string, or immediately before a whitespace and that is immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BJDtfY):

```py
import re
input_text = "xyz T1 VX N1 G1"
pattern = r'\b(?=\w)p?(?:T[X0-4]?)?\s?(?:V[X0-2])?\s?(?:N[X0-3])?\b(?<=\w)'
print(re.findall(pattern, input_text))
# => ['T1 VX N1']
```